# Can a postgres server be publisher for some tables and subscribers for others?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12

I am having 2 servers, server (A,B). Can server A be publisher for table 1 and subscriber for table 2. And server B be publisher for table 2 and subscriber for table 1.

What i reached so far, server A is publisher for table 1 and server B subscribed to it successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is no problem with a setup like that, as long as there are no don't try to replicate the same table in both directions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can definitely set up such a configuration with two servers, A and B, where server A is the publisher for table 1 and the subscriber for table 2, and server B is the publisher for table 2 and the subscriber for table 1. This is often referred to as a bidirectional replication setup.

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible to do so, to achieve this, you will need to configure replication on both servers accordingly.